# What are these light switches?

Tags: lighting, switch, dimmer-switch

I just bought an older home (1959), and it has some odd light switches.

The button is a tap button, and just seems to vary the brightness. The slider seems to turn the lights off and on.

The lights installed when we moved in didn't work, so I replaced them with dimmable LEDs (since I assumed the slider was a dimmer). But it doesn't seem to be a real dimmer.

Has anyone seen these before? and if so, is this the expected behavior?

I'm tempted to just replace them with something standard honestly.[image: Light switches with slider and tap button]

Comment: "*I'm tempted to just replace them with something standard honestly.*" We have a winner! Then put the weird old ones on ebay and see if they surprise you - or not. Would perhaps get better answers if you shut off the circuit at the source and pulled out one to reveal any identifying marks (you'll need that for the ebay listing anyway ;-) You might even find others already there and some idea of prices...) Weird old stuff is sometimes valuable, to someone; doesn't have to be you.

Comment: Those are x10 (or some variation, it was sold under many brand names since the late 1970’s).  Basically early remote control switching, but a technology that just kept going.

Comment: "Ancient lighting control tech don't know what it is, I know, fit LEDs"... Not the best plan.  Don't get me wrong, I love LEDs, but LEDs are fairly picky about which types of dimmers they'll dim with, so that may be your problem right there.  Anytime you're dealing with unknown ancient lighting-control tech, stick with incandescent/halogen until you've got it figured out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Better replace those LEDs with incandescent lights.

## I recognize that switch. It is an X-10 brand, [WS467 Dimmer module](https://www.x10.com/x10-home-automation/switches/ws467.html).

[image: x10 ws467]

Here's the [manual](http://www.authinx.com/manuals/X10/WS467.pdf).

This switch can be controlled in person with your finger, or remotely with a plug-in or wireless controller.  Hopefully the seller left behind some controllers for you.  Otherwise you'd need to buy one to take advantage of remote control.

Basically the larger top momentary pushbutton is the normal on/off control.
The smaller bottom toggle is to 'lock' it off so that nobody can turn it on remotely.

Comment: BTW.  Any time you see those distinctive A-Q 1-16 red and black dials, it's X-10.

Comment: Alright, cool! I'll have to replace that with a normal switch. It's the only one in the house, and no remote was included. Is there any danger to using LED in the meantime?

Comment: Danger is quite a relative term.  You might destroy the lights.  You might destroy the dimmer.  Said destruction could involve a release of heat.  Said heat may induce a fire.  Fire may kill everyone in their sleep. --- Or or it could work just fine.  LED bulbs and any dimming mechanism must be engineered as a complete system to be a good idea to use.  X-10 was frankly invented before LED lights.  If your LEDs are designed to be dimmable by incandescent dimmers you might be fine.  But most aren't, and I doubt you would have posted this Question if it was working well.

Comment: The bottom slider turns power all the way off so you can safely change the bulbs. The push button likely returns it to the last dimmed setting. You can hold the button and it will slowly cycle between bright and dim until you release.